# CIAttributedTextImageGenerator - multiline text image generation problem in iOS 16

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I am usinig `CIAttributedTextImageGenerator` to generate text into `CIImage` in my app.

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: font,
    .foregroundColor: textColor,
    .backgroundColor: textBackgroundColor,
    .shadow: shadow,
    .strokeColor: strokeColor,
    .strokeWidth: strokeWidth
]

let attributedQuote = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)

let textGenerationFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAttributedTextImageGenerator")!
textGenerationFilter.setValue(attributedQuote, forKey: "inputText")
if #available(iOS 16.0, macCatalyst 16.0, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.0, *) {
    textGenerationFilter.setValue(CGFloat(0), forKey: "inputPadding")
}
textGenerationFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: Double(4.0)), forKey: "inputScaleFactor")

guard let textImage = textGenerationFilter.outputImage else {
    return nil
}
```

It was working perfectly until the release of **iOS 16**. In **iOS 16** the behavior changed and now when I try to render a multiline text, the generated text image ends up being way too wide. With each additional line in the text, the width of generated image drastically increases for some reason. The height increases too, but that is obviously to fit the new text line but the width increases without any obvious reasons.

I attached screenshots of what is happening:

[image]

As can been seen, the single liners work perfectly. But with each additional line of text, the rendered image shrinks because the rendered image width becomes wider and wider and it has to shrink to follow the `.aspectFit` rule.

In the end, the width of the generated image becomes even more than its height, despite the text being clearly bigger in height than width.

That never happens on **iOS 15** and the result is as expected there. So is there anything new I am missing either in `CIAttributedTextImageGenerator` or `NSAttributedString` introduced in **iOS 16** that I am missing?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. It would be great if you could open a Feedback ticket for that.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht oh snap. I just discovered that problem quite recently in my app, and I rely on text image generation a lot there. Quite a lot of users use the app too so that is a problem. I am opening a ticket right now, but are there any alternatives you would think of to implement meanwhile? Maybe render UILabel into CIImage? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, if you could get the width the text should actually have (maybe from TextKit or from a `UILabel` with the same text), you could crop the `CIImage` to that width. But that's just a workaround, obviously.

Comment: I just tested your code and can confirm that the text image is way too wide. I guess that `CIAttributedTextImageGenerator` somehow does not consider linebreaks when calculating the image's width. This is clearly a bug, especially when it worked before iOS 16.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht thank you Frank, appreciate the help and testing very much. Cropping might be not a bad idea at all, I might give it a try. I hope my Feedback submission sent to Apple was correct, never did it before.

Comment: I'm confident.  When you post your FB-number here (you can find it below the title of your ticket in Feedback), I will create a duplicate ticket to boost visibility.

Comment: Here it is: FB11785888. Thank you, Frank! Really appreciate your cooperation. There are almost no information on some CoreImage topics out there and it is very nice to have your help 

Comment: Btw, I ended up using a cropping method as you suggested for iOS 16 @FrankRupprecht